# UIBackgroundModes external-accessory

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have added "**App communicates with an accessory**” under the Key “**Required background modes**” in my apps info-plist so that when the app is killed in any way iOS will prompt the user to restart the background syncing for any connected BLE devices.

I have read lots of documentation and seen lots of comments however nothing concert I have only had one other person tell me if I use this our app it will not be accepted into the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `external-accessory` background mode is for MFi accessories, not BLE accessories. There are separate Core Bluetooth background mode entitlements for BLE (`bluetooth-central` and `bluetooth-peripheral`).

If you declare the MFi accessory background mode but your app does not connect to external MFi accessories then you can expect your app to be rejected.

This is covered by clause 2.16 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

> 2.16 Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.

Comment: so only turning off Background Modes can resolve the issue?